# Unable to create access key for AWS S3 data transfer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I recently started using AWS S3 Bucket and facing some issues as I would like to transfer the files from S3 bucket to another server using Boto I Python.

When I tried creating access key and secret key for API, access I got an error that I do not have the permissions to create access key.

I am trying to change the policy as shown below but getting an error:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::s3-sample/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "ViewAndUpdateAccessKeys",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "iam:UpdateAccessKey",
                "iam:CreateAccessKey",
                "iam:ListAccessKeys"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
        }
        
    ]
}
```

This leads to the following error:

```
Policy has invalid action
```

Can someone point to how to set the policy correctly so that it would enable creation of API access keys as well as transfer of files to another server?

Thank you.

Comment: When you say "I tried creating access key and secret key for API", how did you do this? Did you create an IAM User in the IAM management console?

Comment: John..I am trying to create it for myself so that I can move the data to another server. I tried creating the key using My Security Credentials --> Create Key but see a message that I do not have permission and need to request the administrator to create one

Comment: In that case, you cannot create an Access Key. You would need to ask somebody in your company (eg an AWS Admin) to do it for you. If you cannot do it via the console, you cannot do it via Boto3.

Answer (score 2):

IAM [identity-Based Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html#policies_id-based) **don't have** principles. They principle will be deduced automatically when you attach the policy to IAM user, role or group.

However, it seems to me that you are creating [bucket policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-policy-language-overview.html), which have the principle. However, bucket policies do **not apply to** `iam:*` permissions. This would explain your error.

Therefore, I think you should leave your bucket policy in its original state:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::s3-sample/*"
        }        
    ]
}
```

and create [IAM customer managed policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html#customer-managed-policies) which you can attach to the IAM user who requires it:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ViewAndUpdateAccessKeys",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:UpdateAccessKey",
                "iam:CreateAccessKey",
                "iam:ListAccessKeys"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you Marcin...when you say attach it to IAM user who requires it...how should I do it? I am requesting it for myself

Comment: @Ravi You can do it in IAM console. Just go to your IAM user you are using, and there will be option to add policies.